# Actions on Google Push Notifications User Id

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We make extensive use of push notifications in our Action for Google Assistant. Up until recently, we were able to use the notification id received from conv.argments.get('UPDATES_USER_ID') for new users and failing that we could conv.request.conversation.conversationId as an alternative.

If the user resets our Action on their Google Assistant, the original notification id is no longer valid. However, the notification id received for UPDATES_USER_ID post reset is generating an error "The caller does not have permission" with status "PERMISSION_DENIED". If we try to use the alternative, we get the error "Request contains an invalid argument" with status "INVALID_ARGUMENT".

Comment: Could you verify if creating a new Action also generates the same error? If so, it's possible this issue too is impacting Actions without reset. If not, I wonder if you somehow are caching the previous revoked UPDATES_USER_ID.

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to fix the issue by always relying on conv.request.conversation.conversationId as the push notification identifier for corresponding user. Although this entity's value changes with each user conversation, using the value supplied the first time seems to do the trick. Unfortunately, we could not find any documentation or community support on this.